# unable to see java changes after deployment

Tags: aem, aem-6

after I deploy my package with java code changes, I can't see my changes in AEM.

To see may changes, I have to remove my old deployment package bundle from felix console, deploy my code and then restart my AEM instance to see my changes. What must be wrong ?

following are my AEM deployment steps:

```
mvn -Plocal-auto-deploy-with-publish clean install -Dcq.local.author.port=4502 -Dcq.local.publish.port=4503

curl -u admin:admin -F action=reset http://localhost:4502/system/console/slingjsp

curl -u admin:admin -F action=refresh http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp

curl -u admin:admin -F action=reset http://localhost:4503/system/console/slingjsp

curl -u admin:admin -F action=refresh http://localhost:4503/system/console/bundles/org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp
```

Comment: what is the version of new bundle? is it different from old version?

Comment: there is no version <project-Name>-ui-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip is the version. Everytime I deploy my code this should get overwritten with new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing a bundle with same version (without snapshot) apache sling jcr installer will treat it as same and will not install. you will have to keep increasing the version or use a snapshot version so jcr installer knows its not final.

If your are on aem version earlier than aem 6.2, you may also want to check `/system/sling/installer/pauseInstallation` and delete any entries for your bundle there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in 6.2 . What fixed it for me was when you **"Import from server"** in Eclipse from **CRXDe** the **install** folder also gets imported **(If you have it configured within the ui.apps project)** you are syncing your **ui.Apps** or **ui.Content** from **CrxDe** .**Try deleting the install folder that gets synced too**.
Also don't forget checking for extra nodes under **/system/sling/installer/pauseInstallation**

There are hotfixes and CFP available which works for many but in my scenario those didn't work. If it works for you well and good.

Comment: @S.M. Deleting the install folder was the fix for me. Thanks for reviewing I edited the post to make it more clear